# Terminology on algebra.

Tags: probability, abstract-algebra

In Probability textbook, algebra usually defined as follows:

A collection $\Sigma_0$ of subsets of $S$ is called an algebra on $S$ if

- $S \in \Sigma_0$
- $F\in \Sigma_0 \Rightarrow F^c \in \Sigma_0$
- $F,G \in \Sigma_0 \Rightarrow F\cup G \in \Sigma_0$

---

Note:

An algebra in our sense is a true algebra in the algebraists  sense with $\cap$ as product, and symmetric difference $A\Delta B$ as sum, the underlying field of algebra being the field with 2 elements. This is why we prefer algebra of subsets to field to subsets : there is no way that an algebra of subset is a field in the algebraists sense unless $\Sigma_0$ is trivial, that is , $\Sigma_0 = \{S,\phi\}$

---

When I reading David Williams's Probability with Martingales. The author give a note on the terminology of algebra, which make me confused. I know under the product and sum defined as above, $\Sigma_0 = \{S,\phi\}$ is a Field. But I don't know the other things he wrote in this note. Please help me, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In abstract algebra an "[algebra (over a field)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field)" is a collection of elements together with operations of multiplication, addition, and scalar multiplication.  The "field" provides the scalars.  The collection of elements can be multiplied by the scalars in the same way a vector space has multiplication by scalars.  The field with two elements contains only $0$ and $1$ and thus is rather small.  In the algebra defined in your book, the collection of elements is a collection of subsets of a space.  The only scalars one can multiply a set by is zero and one, so the field of scalars is the field with two elements.

If one were to try to make a field of subsets, one would have to define division, which is going to be very tricky for subsets.